# Lexical_cast throws exception

Tags: c++, boost, lexical-cast

boost::lexical_cast throwing exception during converting string to int8_t, but int32_t - norm.

What can be wrong with int8_t ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

int main()
{
    try
    {
        const auto a = boost::lexical_cast<int8_t>("22");
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
    }
    catch( std::exception &e )
    {
        std::cout << "e=" << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: **Question**: Why does `lexical_cast<unsigned char>("127")` throw `bad_lexical_cast`?
**Answer**: Lexical conversion to any char type is simply reading a byte from source. But since the source has more than one byte, the exception is thrown. Please use other integer types such as `int` or `short int`. If bounds checking is important, you can also call `boost::numeric_cast: numeric_cast<unsigned char>(lexical_cast<int>("127"));` from boost [reference](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/frequently_asked_questions.html). In your case `int8_t` is alias for `char`.

Comment: @rafix07 `int8_t` is an alias to `signed char` in all architecture I've seen so far. The problem is that Lexical Cast treats both `signed char` and `unsigned char` just like `char`, rather than integer types. IMHO, a very unhappy design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `boost::lexical_cast`, the character type of the underlying stream is assumed to be char unless either the Source or the Target requires wide-character streaming, in which case the underlying stream uses wchar_t. Following types also can use char16_t or char32_t for wide-character streaming

[Boost Lexical Cast](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/synopsis.html#boost_lexical_cast.synopsis.lexical_cast)

So after doing below changes in your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

int main() 
{
   try
   {
       const auto a = boost::lexical_cast<int8_t>("2");
       const auto b = boost::lexical_cast<int16_t>("22");
       std::cout << a << " and "<< b << std::endl;
   }
   catch( std::exception &e )
   {
      std::cout << "e=" << e.what() << std::endl;
   }
 return 0;
}
```

Gives below output

> 2 and 22

So, I feel that each character is taken as `char`.

So, for `const auto a = boost::lexical_cast<int16_t>("2");` 2 is taken as single  `char` which require int8_t.

And, for `const auto b = boost::lexical_cast<int16_t>("22");` 22 is taken as two `char` values which require int16_t.

I hope it helps!